# How do I clean up my Delegate class to be cleaner?

Tags: sdk, refactoring

I am writing an SDK and wanted to know how to write things more cleanly.

For example, I have a GodManager delegate class (which will be the central class that a user can interact with) (this is pseudocode-ish):

```
public class GodManager {
  private CloudApi cloudApi;
  private SensorApi sensorApi;
  private CacheApi cacheApi;
  .
  . And about 5 more API classes of similar sorts
  .
  GodManager() {
    cloudApi = new CloudApi();
    sensorApi = new SensorApi()
    cacheApi = new CacheApi();
  }

  public void someCloudApiMethodAccess() {
    cloudApi.someCloudApiMethodAccess();
  }
  .
  .
  .  And I have about 25 other methods where GodManager delegates to API classes   
  .      

}
```

How do I allow access for my users via GodManager, but remove these 25 methods that are just proxy methods for each Api class?

I know that Android Wear does something with:

```
public class Wearable {
    public static final com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi DataApi;
    public static final com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi MessageApi;
    public static final com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi NodeApi;
}
```

Where you can access these APIs in your code:

```
Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(...)
```

So I'm guessing that I can mimic this and do something like:

```
class GodManager {
  public static CloudApi CloudApi;

 GodManager {
   CloudApi = new CloudApi();
 }
}
```

Then in my implementation classes, I can:

```
class ImplClass {
  public void method() {
    GodManager.CloudApi.someCloudApiMethodAccess()
  }
}
```

Am I missing anything? Will there be some awkward side-effects that I haven't considered? Any advice would be greatly appreciated in an effort to clean up my GodManager.

Or maybe someone has some other examples that I can look at and learn from?

Comment: What is the reason that the GodManager has to exist at all, if it's just delegating everything? Can the client use the different apis directly? http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/remove-middle-man

Comment: I will look into removing the middle man, but I am also wondering why and how Google Wear currently does it with their API?

Answer (score 0):

Creating public fields is usually an antipattern, although there are some legid uses. The danger lies in the fact that if a user has access to your field, it can do ANYTHING with it.

If `CloudApi` contains public methods or public fields of it's own, that the user should NOT mess with, then te ONLY solution is to make a huge delegate class. If you have full control over `CloudApi`, and/or you can ensure that it's only public members are those that may be safely, and unconditionally, accessed by others, then you can make the instance public. (which is the legid use)

(Note that making a member private and making a public getter for that method that returns the instance, is exactly the same!)

Even then, you're limiting yourself because you're defining your API (of `GodManager`) and you're preventing yourself from EVER extending functionality of the referenced instances. For example, you might want to make calls to `CloudApi` synchronized, or check parameter validity, but don't want (or can) change `CloudApi`. If you have delegate methods, you can extend the functionality without changing your `GodManager` API, and existing users don't break.